# Is the css pixel unit physical size changes if tge screen pixel density changes?

Tags: html, css

I am learning about responsive images and was wondering if I set, for example, an image with a width of 100px and height 100px, then, will that be smaller on a high-resolution screen? Is everything set in pixel (px) (font-size, width etc.) displayed differently on different resolution screens and do developers need to account for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a lot to this question. at its most basic, yes, if you set specific pixel dimensions to an element, then this will show up as the same number of pixels on different devices, but probably different physical dimensions due to varying pixel density.

in CSS (the language used to style web pages) there are other units such as `%`, `em`, and `vw/vh/vmin/vmax` which are relative to something, and these enable developers to lay elements out in a way that is much more flexible to changing screen sizes.

finally there are `@media-query`'s which let developers provide different dimension depending on whether the screen is one size or another. for example, you may wish an element to take up the whole width of the screen on a small screen, but on a larger screen only take up a portion of the screen.

take a look at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com) for more information, particularly [css units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) and [responsive design](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Read up on responsive web design
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp..

You can have a single website design optimized for different devices using various configurations like setting the

`viewport`

This will set the viewport of your page, which will give the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

`Using the width Property`

- Width:
  `<img src="answer.jpg" style="width:100%;">` - Setting the width property allows the image to be scaled up and down if need be.But one thing to note with width property is the image can be scaled up to be larger than its original size. So you can use `max-width`
- Max Width:
  `<img src="img_girl.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">`

If the max-width property is set to 100%, the image will scale down if it has to, but never scale up to be larger than its original size.

`Responsive Text Size`

You can use the `"vw" unit` which stands for viewport width which means the text will match the browser window.

`Media Queries`

You can always define completely different styles for different browser sizes.

```
@media (max-width:800px) {
  .left, .main, .right {
    width:100%; /*The width is 100%, when the viewport is 800px or smaller*/
  }
}
```

`Frameworks`

Alot of frameworks out there already have this done for you and to avoid doing it from scratch you can use them. One example is [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/) .
Most of these frameworks already follow best practices so it would be awesome to use them and also most of them are community driven.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18646989)

Comment: @RolandWeisleder Noted, thanks for the comment

Comment: @RolandWeisleder hope this is clear now

Answer (score 1):

Yes, webpages are being optimised for multiple devices. There are many techniques to be used and you should definitely keep learning them. This knowledge is not just essential for coder, but useful for graphic designers as well.

Very often you can see pages using [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) or [source srcset in the context of an img tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_srcset.asp). One classic is for example to be seen at https://www.apple.com/ -> inspect the page source to see what is going on. There is plenty of good articles regarding the issue at sites such as [@CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/).

Answer (score 1):

PX is a set size. Meaning, an element's height on  a computer will be the same height as on a tablet. It will not resize. Using %, em, vw, or the other ones, they are resizable and they will adjust depending on screen size. You can test by adjusting the window size when you run your program.

Comment: but if that tablet had higher resolution wouldn't the element be smaller?

Comment: Yes, but if you used px throughout the entire site, it would all be relative.